# Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting doubts

Tags: factoring, gauss-sums

I have the following doubts about Gauss algorithm with partial pivoting:

1. Say that I sum to the second row the first row multiplied by $k$. In the $L$ matrix, should I sum to the second row the first row multiplied for $k$ or $-k$?
2. The $P$ matrix contains all row swaps, so for example if I swap the second row with the first one, it will contain the identity matrix with the first and second row swapped. Can I swap rows only before starting the algorithm of also in the middle of it( when I already started pivoting)? And if yes, when I swap two rows, should I perform the swap also on the $L$ matrix?

Comment: I recommend that you change "Gauss algorithm" to "Gaussian elimination" since the former is highly ambiguous. Also the tags do not seem appropriate.

Comment: I think LU decomposition would fit better at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first it should be $-k$ and the swapping of rows is possible while the algorithm is running, you have to swap some parts of the rows in $L$.

Comment: Some parts? Which parts?

Comment: when $\pi$ is the permutation and $l_{ik}$ are the old one the new one should be $l_{\pi(i) k }$

Comment: But after doing this, L could be not triangular anymore.

Comment: no, no the stuff say at the same row, you just swap the position of them inside a row

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't understand what's lπ(i)k, could you explain it with words?

Comment: When $\pi$ is a permution $\pi(i)$ is a number between 1 and $n$ so if the second row and the sixed row are changed, $pi(2)=6$ and $\pi(6)=2$ and so the row entries are changed

Comment: Let's say that L is [1 0 0; 1/2 1 0; 1/4 0 1], I exchange row 2 with 3, will L be [1 0 0; 1/4 1 0; 1/2 0 1] ?

Comment: I answer myself: I tried and it is like this.